# error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to get data from mongodb, for which I have written a service. But I am getting an error like `error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'`

Please help me to resolve this error...

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  result:any;

  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  getUsers() {
    return this._http.get("/api/users")
      .map(result => this.result = result.json().data);
  }

}
```

Comment: Please remove the `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`

Comment: kindly mention your angular version too?

Comment: @Vikas Angular version is 6.0 and rxjs version is 6.1

Comment: a quick fix is `npm install --save rxjs-compat` but I would strongly suggest you  migrate to `HttpClientModule` as mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 6):

You have to import and use the `map` operator differently:

Change

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

to

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Then, do

```
return this._http.get("/api/users")
      .pipe(map(result => this.result = result.json().data));
```

#### Addiontal suggestion from Vikas

Migrate from the Http service to the HttpClient. see [migration guide](https://blog.angular.io/version-5-0-0-of-angular-now-available-37e414935ced)

> To update to `HttpClient`, you’ll need to replace `HttpModule` with
>   `HttpClientModule` from `@angular/common/http` in each of your modules,
>   inject the `HttpClient` service, and remove any `map(res => res.json())`
>   calls, which are no longer needed.

Comment: you should also mention about migrating to  `HttpclientModule` since `HttpModule` is deprecated :)

Comment: As suggested changes done , still getting same error

Comment: @Vikas I don't think it will be directly linked to the problem but it is a very good point! :-)

Comment: @GAJANANJADHAV use `HttpClientModule` which  internally parses the HTTP response body as JSON

Comment: @GAJANANJADHAV What version of rxjs / angular are you using? Try deleting `node_modules` and then a clean `npm install`.

Comment: what about `.pipe(map(...)`

Comment: @Vikas You're absolutely right, not my day. Do you want to add an answer? I'll delete mine.

Comment: @KimKern: below are the version details from package.json file                          {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.33",
    "rxjs": "^6.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },